# Connected another monitor to my laptop, can't display max resolution

Tags: windows, display

I've seen that many have encountered this problem in the past, yet all solutions suggeted don't seem to solve my problem.

I have a HP 15-bs0xx laptop, which has a native 1920x1080 resolution, with Windows 10. I got a Fujitsu SL3220W monitor (that should support 1680x1050), which only has a VGA port. I connected the two with a VGA-HDMI adapter (and more percisly, a both male VGA from the monitor, to a VGA-HDMI adapter).

Now when I try to change the settings of the resolution, for some reason the recommended resolution is 1024x768, and when I try to set the resolution to 1680x1050 (or higher), I get a blacked screen with a messege saying the resolution is out of range.

I changed the refresh rate to 59hz (lowest option), but I still can't use the maximum resolution.

Any help would be very appriciated.

Comment: Do you have latest drivers? Do you have integrated (likely as you are using a laptop...) or dedicated graphics and what is it? Do you have the graphics software directly from the manufacturer or brand? (e.g. AMD Catalyst control center)

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the answer: I changed the cable from VGA-HDMI to DVI(D)-HDMI, and it works :)